# Pack an entire ASP.NET Core 2 App into a Nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget

I am trying to pack an ASP.NET Core 2 App into a Nuget so that I can give this Nuget to another developer, they can create a new Empty ASP.NET Core app and install this Nuget and can run the app and access all the views, etc. (as built in the Nuget).

I tried to pack an app into a Nuget and it works fine. Then, I installed this Nuget into another Empty Web Project, and when I try to run the app, I get the exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

When adding the  Nuget, I can see the Views folder created (a replica of what is created in the packed project). However, when running the app, they are not being fetched.

Any idea how to make this work? I need to develop an entire app and share it as a Nuget, so that other developers can add more features, etc.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to create a step in the Nuget to copy the view files into the project. Either that or compile the views into the DLL, possibly writing a custom view engine to extract them.

Comment: They are already added as Content and being copied inside the Nuget and I can see them in the Empty project once the Nuget is being installed. Still they are not being accessed!

Comment: Where can you see them in the empty project after installing the Nuget package?

Comment: I see a Views folder and has all the sub folders and cshtml files. Also, I see a small square with an arrow on the bottom-left side of the Views folders.